# Графический интерфейс в Python

Tags: python, tkinter, окно

А не подскажете, как из одного окна графического интерфейса вызывать другое? (Код программы в Python.)

**Добавлено из комментария.**

Ну, вот простейший пример, создаю файл proba.py:

```
from Tkinter import*
tk1=Tk()
```

Далее создаю файл, с помощью которого хочу открыть предыдущий:

```
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-
from Tkinter import*
from proba import*
def button1_clicked():
    tk1.mainloop()
button1=Button(text=u'жми!',command=button1_clicked)
button1.pack()
tk=Tk()
tk.mainloop()
```

В результате вылезают оба окна, при этом кнопка по сути не работает...

Comment: А что значит "из одного окна графического интерфейса вызывать другое"?

Comment: А о каком интерфейсе и операционной системе идет речь? PyGTK, PyQT4?

Comment: Система windows 7.  Делаю графический интерфейс, как подключать модули к программе я знаю, хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, можно было открывать другой интерфейс... Просто при обращении к модулю возникают ошибки и программа не работает должным образом.

Comment: Похоже путаница с терминологией. Постарайтесь не употреблять без нужды мудрёных иностранных слов, а постарайтесь объяснить на пальцах. И желательно с демонстрацией неработающего кода.

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

C tkinter такой фокус не пройдет. Два экземпляра Tk() в одном скрипте корректно работать не будут.

Два варианта:

1. Переписать оконный интерфейс в
       импортируемом скрипте из
       самостоятельного фрейма в виджет
       Toplevel. Многооконный интерфейс в
       tkinter реализуется именно так.
       Примеры найдете.
2. Если лень
       переписывать, вызывайте модуль
       отдельным процессом:

   import subprocess

   button1=Button(text=u'жми!',command=lambda: subprocess.Popen('proba.py'))

Comment: Первое -- нормально. Именно так всё в tk (который используется в tkinter) и других event-driven приложениям делается. Второе, даже если и будет работать -- какой-то хитрый изврат.

mainloop -- "основной цикл", ожидание событий. Их два в одном потоке быть не может.

Answer (score 0):

Второе окно рисует у тебя `import`, а не функция.